# Building the Android Project using Ant/Maven

Tags: android

Do we require Ant/Maven to build an android project? I want detail information regarding building an android project using ANt/Maven.

Comment: Ant and Maven are both optional to build Android project, if you use IDE like Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Maven to build Android apps.  You *do* need Ant, or Eclipse.

Here's a basic training guide to [creating an Android project](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html).

If you want to use Maven, you can.  There's a popular plugin for maven with [instructions here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/GettingStarted).

Comment: Lucas, Thanks a lot for your reply. right now I am refactoring some modules in an Android project. So do I need to build the project with Ant again?